# I Can't install my Unlocked package application

Tags: salesforcedx, package-install, unlocked-package

I'm trying to build an unlocked package with a custom namespace. I've create a package and a package version. but when i'm installing the package version i got this error:

```
This app can't be installed.
There are problems that prevent this package from being installed.
(Contact_Record_Page) Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)  
There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Template namespace:ContactPageTemplate doesn't exist.".
```

But it works well if i push the code into my Dev and scratch org from sfdx with `source:deploy` and `source:push` command.

Thanks

Comment: Is this meant to be part of a managed package? If not, you can't use a namespace.

Comment: ah alright, i didn't know that. Thanks for your answer.